# How do in store more than 838:59:59 time value in my sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is I want to store the more than 1000:00:00 need to store in the database.In case I may use the `VARCHAR` data type . But problem is I am using time sum query it also show only 838:59:59 as sum . How do I fix it?

time sum Query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `ot_hour` ) ) ) AS timeSum FROM groupotreques
```

Comment: Using date or varchar won't work. You can try to use mediumtext

Comment: i also not working bro .it will return 838:59:59.999999

Comment: using  mediumtext i can store the more than 838:59:59 value but i but time sum query not working correctly

Comment: Store seconds instead. Numbers can be pretty dang big. There's little that can be done with `TIME` that can't be done with numeric types.

Comment: can write query in different way to get the sum of the time query

Comment: 'TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html - try explaining what you are trying to do and someone may be able to suggest an alternate approach.